# What is meant by "congregational honor" regarding disallowing women reading the Torah publically?

Tags: women, torah-reading, kavod, tractate-megillah

The Talmud Bavli ([Megillah 23a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.23a.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) says that while, if a woman read from the Torah it counts towards the required 7 *aliyot*, the *chachamim* disallowed it because of *kavod hatzibbur* - the respect for the congregation.

What is this *kavod hatzibbur*? Is it a concern of men seeing women during prayers, or that mean will be distracted by viewing a woman on the men's side? We already use a *mechitza* for that concern. Also, that concern seems to be more of an "individual" concern, not a tzibbur concern.

I've read that public Torah reading is an obligation only for the tzibbur. I.e., when there is a tzibbur - i.e. a minyan - the Torah must be read publicly. So, it seems that having a woman read the Torah is considered disrespectful in some way to the congregation meaning the group unit. What exactly is disrespectful, here? What's the concern?

Comment: I have written on this topic extensively [here](https://torahclarity.blogspot.com/2017/02/the-role-of-women.html).

Comment: @tcdw B"N, I will view this tonight. I spoke a bit about this in my shul during Shavuot. At least, "locally", it's a hot topic.

Comment: https://www.herzog.ac.il/vtc/tvunot/netuim/netuim20_baras.pdf

Answer (score 3):

[This article](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/shiur-06-public-torah-reading-women) offers an interesting interpretation of the concern. Excerpts:

> Rav Ben-Zion Uziel understands the expression “kevod ha-tzibbur” in a
>   different manner. In the course of a discussion of the right of women
>   to vote in elections and to be elected into office, Rav Uziel rejects
>   the assertion that the mixed seating of men and women in government
>   offices constitutes immodest behavior (Mishpetei Uziel, IV, Choshen
>   Mishpat, no. 6). Among other sources, he mentions our passage.
>   According to him, Chazal did not forbid calling women to the Torah
>   because of immodesty, but only because of kevod ha-tzibbur. From this
>   Rav Uziel concludes that when people assemble for a serious purpose,
>   there is no concern about immodesty, even if the participants include
>   both men and women.
>
> According to Rav Uziel, the prohibition against women reading from the
>   Torah is not connected to the issue of modesty. Why then did Chazal
>   forbid them to be called to read from the Torah?  He answers: “So that
>   people not say that there is nobody among the men who knows how to
>   read from the Torah.” This explanation is based on the practice that
>   was current in the days of Chazal, that each person called to the
>   Torah would read his portion out loud. Were women to be called to the
>   Torah and read from it, the impression would be created that the men
>   are incapable of doing so, and therefore they require the assistance
>   of the women.
>
> Chazal apparently based their concerns on the simple assumption that
>   it is men who regularly participate in communal prayer services. It is
>   men who are obligated in communal prayer, and it is men who can form
>   the required quorum. Even had Chazal not barred women from active
>   participation in public Torah reading, it may be assumed that most of
>   the Torah readers would have been men, as it is they who go more often
>   to synagogue, and it is they who are required for a quorum.
>   Furthermore, according to many authorities, the majority of the
>   readers must be adult males even if women and minors are included
>   (Rema, Orach Chayyim 282:3). According to most of the Posekim, as well
>   as according to accepted practice, women are not obligated to
>   participate in public Torah reading, and therefore nobody would expect
>   them to acquire the necessary expertise; this obligation is cast upon
>   men. In such circumstances, were women to be called to the Torah, it
>   would give the impression that the men – who are obligated to conduct
>   the Torah reading and to hear it – are not fit to do this. When the
>   men of a community are perceived as negligent in fulfilling their
>   religious duties, this is a stain on the community.

The article offers various angles on this issue. I have viewed some other articles on this topic, and, this is just one take - the one I feel is the most substantive and "intelligent". There is a separate paper that discusses whether *kavod hatzibbur* may be waived by the congregation regarding women reading Torah. There seems to be varying opinions. When, I can, I will update this answer with a link or two to the various articles.

Comment: Why appeal to Rav Uziel? This is explicitly the Ritva’s opinion on the cited Gemara (at least the part defining Kavod Hatzibbur).

Comment: @DonielF Please add that to the above answer or write your own. You've obviously found something that I didn't.